# Array laravel validation " * " returns true

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js, post, request

I'm trying to validate an array 
Array :

```
location_id: [
     {id: 1, name: "Line 1"}, 
     {id: 2, name: "Line 2"}, 
     {id: 3, name: "Flex 1"}, 
     {id: 4, name: "Flex 2"}
],
name: "Failure 1",
station_id: [
     {id: 1, name: "Station 1"}, 
     {id: 2, name: "Station 2"}
]
```

when the data is sent to the server it returns true 
validation code:

```
 $rules = [
     'location_id.*.id'  =>  'required',
     'station_id.*.id'  =>   'required'
 ];

 Validator::make($request->all(),$rules)->passes());
```

it should return `false` if the array `location_id` is empty or `location_id[0].id == null` but is returning true if the array is sent empty

if the rules are specified in the following way it works but sometimes i will add 2,3 or more arrays inside a `location_id` or `station_id`

```
 $rules = [
     'location_id.0.id'  =>  'required',
     'station_id.0.id'  =>   'required'
 ];
```

Comment: You could use the [filled](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-filled) validation instead.

Comment: is not working :(

Comment: There is no null id in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule

```
$rules = [
     'location_id'  =>  'required|array|min:1',
     'location_id.*.id'  =>   'required',
     'station_id.*.id'  =>   'required'
];
```

Add `'station_id'  =>  'required|array|min:1'` to `$rules` if you want to return `false` if `station_id` is empty.

Comment: let me try it !